# Was sind "Attributions" auf Deutsch?

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request, legal-terminology

Ich bin aktuell an der Internationalisierung eines Open-Source-Projektes beteiligt.

Unter anderem muss ich das Wort "Attributions" übersetzen.

Dieses Wort wird als Titelzeile für die rechtlich notwendigen ... "Referenzen" für verwendete Technologien benutzt.

Zuerst dachte ich an "Danksagungen", dann aber fiel mir auf, dass es auch eine Sektion "Special Thanks" gibt.

Ich habe auch ein Onlinewörterbuch bemüht, kann aber mit

> "Zuschreibungen", "Attribuierungen", "Zuordnungen"

und Ähnlichem für diesen Kontext nichts anfangen.

Also wie übersetze ich das?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Die deutsche Übersetzung der [Creative Commons License 3.0.](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/de/) spricht hier von **Namensnennung**:

> **Namensnennung** — Sie müssen **angemessene Urheber- und Rechteangaben** machen, einen Link zur Lizenz beifügen und angeben, ob Änderungen vorgenommen wurden. Diese Angaben dürfen in jeder angemessenen Art und Weise gemacht werden, allerdings nicht so, dass der Eindruck entsteht, der Lizenzgeber unterstütze gerade Sie oder Ihre Nutzung besonders.

und in der [GNU General Public License](http://www.gnu.de/documents/gpl.de.html) ist von **Autorenschaftshinweisen** die Rede:

> 7 b. die Anforderung, spezifizierte sinnvolle rechtliche Hinweise oder **Autorenschaftshinweise** in diesem Material oder in den angemessenen rechtlichen Hinweisen, die von den sie enthaltenen Werken angezeigt werden, zu erhalten, oder

Vielleicht sollte man jeweils auf den Terminus zurückgreifen, der in der offiziellen Übersetzung der jeweiligen Lizenz genannt ist.

Answer (score 4):

Da ausdrücklich nach einem rechtlichen Begriff gefragt ist, wäre der exakte Terminus für Deutschland wohl *Urheberbezeichnungen*:

> § 13 Anerkennung der Urheberschaft. Der Urheber hat das Recht auf Anerkennung seiner Urheberschaft am Werk. Er kann bestimmen, ob das Werk mit einer Urheberbezeichnung zu versehen und welche Bezeichnung zu verwenden ist.

([Gesetz über Urheberrecht und verwandte Schutzrechte](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/urhg/))

Als Überschrift oder Menüpunkt in einem Programm, das sich an die Allgemeinheit wendet, scheint mir der Begriff aber nicht angemessen. Anstelle einer exakten Wiedergabe von *attribution* wäre es sinnvoller, zu beschreiben, worum es eigentlich geht, also etwa *in diesem Programm verwendete Softwarekomponenten* oder etwas Ähnliches.

Für Bilder ist *Quellennachweis* verbreitet.

Answer (score 1):

Wie wäre es mit dem von Dir gebrauchten "verwendete Technologien" oder mit "Vorleistungen" oder mit "Bibliotheken"?

*Technologien* ist m.E. zu aufgeblasen und allgemein. Bei der Verwendung von Quantencomputern, Kernspintomatographen und Röhrenverstärkern würde ich von Technologien reden. Hier klingt es für mich eher wie Bibliotheken, Funktionalitäten, Modulen oder ähnlichem.